# Can't get Phone Gap to build in Xcode

Tags: ios, cordova

This is my first time working with phone gap, and I am pretty new to app development and objective-c. I've followed the phone gap documentation on getting set up but when I run their basic "hello world" application I get an error in CDVSound.m

The error says:
"Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *' "
Referring to:

```
NSString* docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

I am running Xcode 4.4.1 (can't upgrade) with Phone gap version 2.7

Any ideas? Does it have anything to do with literal syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. It's because for that statement to work I needed the iOS 6.0 sdk. I was using the 5.1 sdk.

Placing:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 60000
@interface NSDictionary(subscripts)
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end

@interface NSMutableDictionary(subscripts)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
@end

@interface NSArray(subscripts)
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end

@interface NSMutableArray(subscripts)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end
#endif
```

at the header of my file works.